# Dynamic font resizing in collectionview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

for my app I implemented a collectionview showing cards, that are rotated in a carousel-like animation. My problem is that the cards themselves resize correctly when swiped, but the fonts stay the same size or resize incorrectly. To be specific, the answers (bottommost 5 labels) are in a stackview.

Things I tried:

- AutoLayout
- Autoshrink
- `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`
- any number of different constraints

I attached a few screenshots below, where I colored the labels for better visibility.

[image: screenshots of my page view controller]

Comment: What method/library/framework are you using to display this card-like page view controller?

Comment: I used the standard collectionview with a custom layout to enable paging for the cards

Comment: How are you scaling your views? If you're not using a scale transform, that might be worth looking at.

Comment: Right now I'm just changing the size attribute of the view in my custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout. I suppose that's not the best why judging by your comment. I'll have a look into it

Comment: @lukelle - here is a simple example to give you an idea. You can paste it right into a new Playground page to view: https://gist.github.com/DonMag/b33b8685bf905cf9b7a9e919acdda375

Comment: Scale transform (CGAffineTransform) did it for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post your answer here (not as a comment) so I can close this question?

Thanks again!

Comment: Done - glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To change the size of a view and have all of it's subviews / buttons / labels / etc scale with it - *including* label fonts, you are better off using `CGAffineTransform` for scaling.

Here is a simple example. It can be pasted into a Playground page to see the effect:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    let theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.axis = .vertical
        sv.distribution = .equalCentering
        sv.alignment = .center
        return sv
    }()

    let theContainerView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()

    let btn: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Tap to Scale", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return b
    }()

    // on button tap, scale the Container view by 50% both ways
    // note that Container view's subviews also scale
    func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        theContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the button to self.view
        self.view.addSubview(btn)

        // button position
        btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true

        // add a target for the button tap
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // add our "Container" view
        view.addSubview(theContainerView)

        // add our Stack view to the Container view
        theContainerView.addSubview(theStackView)

        // add 5 labels to the Stack view
        for i in 1...5 {

            let label = UILabel()
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
            label.text = "This is Label \(i)"
            label.backgroundColor = .cyan
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            theStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

        }

        // pin Container view 20-pts from the bottom of the button, and 8-pts from left, right and bottom
        theContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        theContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        theContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        theContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

        // pin Stack view 8-pts from top, left, right and bottom of the Container view
        theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        theStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        theStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainerView.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
        theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true

    }

}

let vc = TestViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```